# How to know the response time of my WPF application

Tags: .net, testing, response

I have a very simple application in WPF. It has some buttons, textboxes and shapes.
Some of the buttons open another WPF windows, while other are showing me messageboxes.

How can I know the response time of my application? In other words, how can I measure the time between clicking on a button and showing the other window?

Comment: Use a `StopWatch` also note that your click event will fire soon only when your main thread is free, else that will count there.

Answer (score 0):

This will measure the time from hitting the ctor to Loaded

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    public Window1()
    {
        sw.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(900);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sw.Stop();
        tbTime.Text = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
    }
}
```

Could even pass the stopwatch to the windows

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw;
    public Window1()
    {
        sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(900);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Window1(System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch SW)
    {
        sw = SW;
        if (!SW.IsRunning) sw.Restart();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(900);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sw.Stop();
        tbTime.Text = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What meaning has the sleep in the constructor?

Comment: Meaning or purpose?  The meaning of sleep is to stop or pause for that number of milliseconds.

Comment: Ok. Thought there was a deeper reason :)